# Animation Render Glitches

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I have been struggling with this issue for some time now. Every once in a while, when I render a frame it will have bizarre...glitches, is all I can call them.

Animations are where this is most noticeable and prevalent, by nature of them requiring so many frames. However, this issue has occurred on single frames as well.

Two main types appear. Most frequently they are large glowing areas, usually a highly saturated red (but sometimes other colors as well). They vary in size greatly. The other is a full-on static effect that covers a significant portion of the image. (Both can be seen in the attached video). It seems almost random, as a re-render seldom produces the same results.

I believe this *might* be caused by the Glare compositing node interacting with fireflies and the denoiser, but I am not entirely sure. It is almost certainly not a compression artifact, as it is visible in the Image Editor even before being exported as an image or video (I think it happens in the compositing stage). I am not sure if this is a glitch, or what, or if my diagnosis is even correct; but it has been plaguing me across countless .blend files for some time and I have been unable to figure it out.

I am using Blender 2.80 Mac. CPU rendering.

Help!

(The attached video has a very low resolution and sample count, but the same problems occur with better qualities and lighting as well.)
https://youtu.be/tJpcI5edvic

Comment: Have you tried rendering the same scene out to PNG frames without compositing? That way you can create a new blend file, import the frames as an image strip and play with compositing afterwards?

Comment: Wouldn't that remove some of the data needed for certain compositing actions? (Vectors, Z-depth, etc.)?

Comment: You can render out Z depth pass seperately.  You're right though, it does make things more complicated.  I didn't realize that you're setup was so intricate.